# Dynamically allocating 2-dimensional array in Struct (in C)

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a structure called container that has two fields: **labels** and **linked_to_containers**; The field labels is designed to be a 2-dimensional array of int, and the field linked_to_containers is designed to be a 2-dimensional array of int pointers. On top of this, I also have an array of `struct container` that are dynamically created in the initiation program. I have the following code written down, but one thing I'm unsure about is the first `malloc` I used inside of the function `container_init()`. As the `struct container` still does not have its size initialized, is this the right way to do `malloc` for creating an array of struct container?

Please see my question in my comments in the code, and I will appreciate your feedback.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct container {
    int *labels[2];                  /* two-dimensional array of int */
    int **linked_to_container[2];    /* two-dimensional array of pointers to label */
} container;

int get_next_container_index(int current_container_index, int max_index)
{
    if (max_index - current_container_index >= 1)
    {
        return current_container_index + 1;
    }
    else 
        return 0;        /* elements at two ends are linked */
}

container *allcontainers;   /* an array for all containers */

void container_init(int num_containers, int column_num)
{
    /* is this right to malloc memory on the array of container when the struct size is still unknown?*/
    allcontainers = (container *) malloc(num_containers * sizeof(container));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_containers; i++)
    {
        container *current_container = &allcontainers[i];
        current_container->labels[0] = malloc(column_num * sizeof(int));
        current_container->labels[1] = malloc(column_num * sizeof(int));

        current_container->linked_to_container[0] = malloc(column_num * sizeof(int *));
        current_container->linked_to_container[1] = malloc(column_num * sizeof(int *));

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < column_num; j++)
        {
            current_container->labels[0][j] = 0;     /* initialize all labels to 0 */
            current_container->labels[1][j] = 0;

            int next_container = get_next_container_index(i, num_containers - 1);     /* max index in all_containers[] is num_containers-1 */
            current_container->linked_to_container[0][j] = &(allcontainers[next_container]->labels[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The line in question seems perfectly fine to me, the size of `struct container` is well-known, because of its definition. The only size not known is the size of the arrays that the pointers in the struct will eventually point to, but that doesn't affect the size of the pointers themselves and thus also not the struct's size.

The only issue I see is here:

```
current_container->linked_to_container[0][j] = &(allcontainers[next_container]->labels[0]);
```

`linked_to_container[0][j]` is of type `int*`, but `labels[0]` is of type `int*` and therefore `&(labels[0])` is of type `int**`. I am not sure what you try to accomplish here, but you probably need another index to `labels[0][...]` or `&` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks @Nabla. The labels[0] is the first row of my two dimenstional array labels[][], so labels[0] is of type int * for an array of size column_num.

Comment: @TonyGW Correct, but then you also take the address of it, so it becomes `int**`.

Comment: or should I just use this: current_container->linked_to_container[0][j] = allcontainers[next_container].labels[0];

Comment: @TonyGW Then at least the types would match, I don't know what you are trying to archive with the code, so maybe that's correct.

Comment: the field **linked_to_container** is a two-dimenstional array of int pointers, which points to another container's label.

Comment: @TonyGW Only that there is not **one** label, but `2*column_num` different labels... I guess that you want to add another index to `labels[0]` then, so that you point to an actual label.